# Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql connection string problem

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm trying to create **MySQL** server container, save it's data to volume and then connect to it from another container with ASP.NET Core application. I stucked on part with connection to MySQL server.

My **connection string**:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ProductDbConnection": "server=0.0.0.0:13306;port=3306;User=root;Password=qwerty;Database=products;"
  }
```

Adding **DbContext** to service container in **ASP.NET Core application**:
`

```
var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion("8.0.31");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProductDbContext>(
    options => options.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductDbConnection"), serverVersion,
    options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), null)));
```

My docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleApp.dll"]
```

When I ran my ASP.NET Core application container i got errors messages like this:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
2022-12-28 11:34:21       An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server '0.0.0.0:13306'.
2022-12-28 11:34:21 info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10404]
```

looks like it lost my database name from connection string. I tried to change server address to address like in network bridge, but result is the same. Help me please. Feels like i missed a little detail somewhere.

Comment: I think this is not correct `server=0.0.0.0:13306` last 4 digit is your port which you already been defined. `port=3306`. Instead it should like `server=0.0.0.0;` or `server=localhost;` or `server=any IP adress;` without `:13306` part. You can refer to this [`official document`](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/master/README.md#4-read-the-ef-core-documentation). Valid servier address would be `server=0.0.0.0;`

Comment: You can even specify your mysql server ip as `127.0.0.1` in your docker compose file as well.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, thank you. Solution was to specify 'bind-address' in mysql server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Glad to know it it has resolved.